# How To Fix Nested Sortable Divs in Jquery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to create a UI that allows the user to take a set of window divs in the DOM and drag them around, sometimes appending divs as children of other divs and sometimes pulling those children out to a parent level.  I have a working example but it is extremely touchy when you try to append a "uncle" div to a "nephew" div or vice versa.  There is about a 1px leeway to nest the div, as you can see in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/124/.

How can I "loosen" the sensitivity so it is not so quick to move on to the next sortable in the tree while clicking and dragging?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to look at snap, snapMode and snapTolerance. [See the API here.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jeff.  It appears to me that snap, snapMode, and snapTolerance are part of the Draggable component's options and not  necessarily sortables.  Are these options also available to sortables?

Comment: Sortable inherits from draggable so they are applicable

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it to a large extent.  Thanks to a suggestion by Ryan Niemeyer at Knockmeout.net, the problem was largely rectified by setting a min-height on the container div and adding a little padding to make sure there is a target at the drop zone.  Here is the fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/130/  The only difference you'll see is the sort-fix class with padding and min-height and the sortable tags are classed as sort-fix.